# Kotlin vararg: how to set null to vararg that don't throw NullPointerException?

Tags: kotlin, nullpointerexception

My function：

```kotlin
    fun func(vararg objects: Any?) {
    }
```

When I call `func(null)`, got Exception: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter, parameter objects.
And I saw decompile java code is this:

```java
   public static final void func(@NotNull Object... objects) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(objects, "objects");
      printer.v(new Object[]{objects});
   }
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You can't have a null in a vararg in kotlin, [this](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/whether-it-is-the-only-way-to-convert-nullable-case-vararg-parameter-from-java-to-kotlin-replace-with-array-some/2120) post on kotlinlang confirms it. ```Note that vararg parameters are, as a rule, never nullable, because in Java there is no good way to distinguish between passing null as the entire vararg array versus passing null as a single element of a non-null vararg array.```

Comment: @Alex.T That looks like an answer to me :-)

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a null in a vararg in kotlin, [this post on kotlinlang](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/whether-it-is-the-only-way-to-convert-nullable-case-vararg-parameter-from-java-to-kotlin-replace-with-array-some/2120)
confirms it.

> Note that vararg parameters are, as a rule, never nullable, because in
> Java there is no good way to distinguish between passing null as the
> entire vararg array versus passing null as a single element of a
> non-null vararg array.